# What does the fingerprint mean when creating a discord account and how can I obtain it using python selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, discord

[image: ![]

I'm not sure what the fingerprint means or how to obtain it without looking at the network traffic.

Comment: Seems like that would be a browser fingerprint.  So a site can read certain details via javascript, web assembly, and native server language to identify your specific browser/ip/location, etc...  This helps secure an account by knowing when a new device has accessed the account.  (they can then notify you when that happens...)  How to access that depends on the site and the technique used... probably easiest to just use wire shark or something like that.